# Gulp-file-include doesn't work with gulp.watch

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, gulp-watch

I want to use `gulp-file-include` to assemble the index.html from different HTML files. The dist folder contains all production files. The problem is that `gulp-watch` does not recognize if an HTML file has changed, so the HTML file in the dist folder will not be updated while I run watch.

How can I customize gulp so that `gulp-watch` also detects these changes in real-time?

```
-- dist
---- css
---- js
---- vendor
---- index.html
-- res
---- js
---- scss
-- src
---- footer.html
---- nav.html
gulpfile.js
index.html
```

**index.html**

```
@@include('./src/nav.html')
@@include('./src/footer.html')
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
"use strict";

// Load plugins
const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();
const cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
const del = require("del");
const gulp = require("gulp");
const header = require("gulp-header");
const merge = require("merge-stream");
const plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
const fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');

// Load package.json for banner
const pkg = require('./package.json');

// BrowserSync
function browserSync(done) {
    browsersync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./dist/"
        },
        port: 3000
    });
    done();
}

// BrowserSync reload
function browserSyncReload(done) {
    browsersync.reload();
    done();
}

// Clean vendor
function clean() {
    return del(["./dist/vendor/"]);
}

// Bring third party dependencies from node_modules into vendor directory
function modules() {
    // Bootstrap
    var bootstrap = gulp.src('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/bootstrap'));
    // Font Awesome CSS
    var fontAwesomeCSS = gulp.src('./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/fontawesome-free/css'));
    // Font Awesome Webfonts
    var fontAwesomeWebfonts = gulp.src('./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/fontawesome-free/webfonts'));
    // jQuery Easing
    var jqueryEasing = gulp.src('./node_modules/jquery.easing/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/jquery-easing'));
    // jQuery
    var jquery = gulp.src([
        './node_modules/jquery/dist/*',
        '!./node_modules/jquery/dist/core.js'
    ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/jquery'));
    return merge(bootstrap, fontAwesomeCSS, fontAwesomeWebfonts, jquery, jqueryEasing);
}

// CSS task
function css() {
    return gulp
        .src("./res/scss/**/*.scss")
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: "expanded",
            includePaths: "./node_modules",
        }))
        .on("error", sass.logError)
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(header(banner, {
            pkg: pkg
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min"
        }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

// JS task
function js() {
    return gulp
        .src([
            './res/js/*.js',
            '!./res/js/*.min.js',
            '!./res/js/contact_me.js',
            '!./res/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js'
        ])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(header(banner, {
            pkg: pkg
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

function html() {
    return gulp
        .src(['index.html'])
        .pipe(fileinclude({
            prefix: '@@',
            basepath: '@file'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

// Watch files
function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch("./res/scss/**/*", css);
    gulp.watch(["./res/js/**/*", "!./dist/js/**/*.min.js"], js);
    gulp.watch("./**/*.html", browserSyncReload);
}

// Define complex tasks
const vendor = gulp.series(clean, modules);
const build = gulp.series(vendor, gulp.parallel(css, js, html));
const watch = gulp.series(build, gulp.parallel(watchFiles, browserSync));

// Export tasks
exports.css = css;
exports.js = js;
exports.html = html;
exports.clean = clean;
exports.vendor = vendor;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = build;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BrowserSync is amazing but always seems tough to get it running the way you want! I endedup creating a little test projct to debug your gulpfile.js

Here is a tested, working version of your code, notes below:

```
'use strict';

// Load plugins
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const del = require('del');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const header = require('gulp-header');
const merge = require('merge-stream');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');

// Load package.json for banner
const pkg = require('./package.json');

// BrowserSync
function server(done) {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './dist/'
        },
        port: 3000
    });
    done();
}

// server reload
function browserSyncReload(done) {
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
};

// Clean vendor
function clean() {
    return del(['./dist/vendor/']);
}

// Bring third party dependencies from node_modules into vendor directory
function modules() {
    // Bootstrap
    var bootstrap = gulp.src('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/bootstrap'));
    // Font Awesome CSS
    var fontAwesomeCSS = gulp.src('./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/fontawesome-free/css'));
    // Font Awesome Webfonts
    var fontAwesomeWebfonts = gulp.src('./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/fontawesome-free/webfonts'));
    // jQuery Easing
    var jqueryEasing = gulp.src('./node_modules/jquery.easing/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/jquery-easing'));
    // jQuery
    var jquery = gulp.src([
        './node_modules/jquery/dist/*',
        '!./node_modules/jquery/dist/core.js'
    ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/jquery'));
    return merge(bootstrap, fontAwesomeCSS, fontAwesomeWebfonts, jquery, jqueryEasing);
}

// CSS task
function css() {
    return gulp
        .src('./res/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'expanded',
            includePaths: './node_modules',
        }))
        .on('error', sass.logError)
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(header(banner, {
            pkg: pkg
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream({match: '**/*.css'}));
}

// JS task
function js() {
    return gulp
        .src([
            './res/js/*.js',
            '!./res/js/*.min.js',
            '!./res/js/contact_me.js',
            '!./res/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js'
        ])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(header(banner, {
            pkg: pkg
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
}

function html() {
    return gulp
        .src(['index.html'])
        .pipe(fileinclude({
            prefix: '@@',
            basepath: '@file'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
}

// Watch files
function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch('./res/scss/**/*', css);
    gulp.watch(['./res/js/**/*', '!./dist/js/**/*.min.js'], gulp.series(js, browserSyncReload));
    gulp.watch(['./src/**/*.html', 'index.html'], gulp.series(html, browserSyncReload));
}

// Define complex tasks
const vendor = gulp.series(clean, modules);
const build = gulp.series(vendor, gulp.parallel(css, js, html));
const watch = gulp.series(build, server, watchFiles);

// Export tasks
exports.css = css;
exports.js = js;
exports.html = html;
exports.clean = clean;
exports.vendor = vendor;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.browserSyncReload = browserSyncReload;
exports.server = server;
exports.default = build;
```

Only a couple of bits had to change to get this working:

1. I think the main issue you were seeing was you weren’t recompiling the html on change, it was just reloading the browser. I’ve updated the watch html from: `gulp.watch('./**/*.html', browserSyncReload);` to: `gulp.watch(['./src/**/*.html', 'index.html'], gulp.series(html, browserSyncReload));`
2. The `stream` is meant for injecting in code onto the page, so won’t work as you want for the `html` and `js`, so I’ve removed it from the tasks and replaced with a `reload` in the watch task.
3. Exports for `browserSyncReload` and `server` were needed
4. It seemed there was a race issue with `watchFiles` and `browserSync` when running in parallel, so they now run in series. ie: The server builds first, then the files are watched.

Changes that weren’t required but happened along the way:

1. Having a function named `browserSync` and const named `browsersync` was confusing me, so the function has been renamed to `server` and the const is now `browserSync`.
2. My editor config set all your quotes to single, rather than a mix.
3. I have set the `stream` in the css task to only `match: '**/*.css'`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
gulp.watch("./**/*.html", browserSyncReload);
```

to

```
gulp.watch("./src/**/*.html", browserSyncReload);
```